# update selected rows column value in datatable sql

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

Am having four rows in the database.I selected two rows  from it and save in a datatable. I need to update the date column for the two rows in datatable.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{ 
   SqlCommand date1 = new SqlCommand("update OutletId set Date=dateadd(dd,1,Date)", sqlc);
   date1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But the above  query update  all the four rows. Is there solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put the `Where` condition in your query.

Replace this query :

```
update OutletId set Date=dateadd(dd,1,Date)
```

With this :

```
update OutletId set Date=dateadd(dd,1,Date) Where yourField=yourValue
```

Since you are using `DataTable`, you will have to pass the value for `Where` clause using the `dt` parameter.

Put up a loop for your datatable rows and pass the `Where` clause parameter using something like this : `dt.Rows[index]["columnName"].ToString()`

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but i need to update the two rows in datatable if i use Where it will only update only one row

Comment: That is exactly why I have suggested putting up a `for` or `foreach` loop to loop over your datatable rows in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use where clause for specific row updation if there are 100 records then update without where clause affect all rows so u need to add where cluse with primary or unique key in your table

```
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        SqlCommand date1 = new SqlCommand("update OutletId set Date=dateadd(dd,1,Date) where pk="+primary key, sqlc);
        date1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```